# Which "one hundred rules" did Harry and Ron break to find the Chamber of Secrets?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, laws

Towards the end of *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* Professor McGonagall says that Harry and Ron broke "a hundred school rules".

> “Very well,” Professor McGonagall prompted him as he paused, “so you found out where the entrance was — breaking a hundred school rules into pieces along the way, I might add —"

### Which hundred rules did they break?

Comment: Strongly related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102543/what-rules-were-they-breaking-by-making-the-polyjuice-potion?lq=1

Comment: @randal'thor that question inspired this question. Possibly those fifty are included in these hundred.

Comment: I'm pretty sure she's simply hyperbolizing.

Comment: @DVK yeah, but I'm hoping that someone can make a list of all of the rules they *did* break.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- First of all, she's probably exaggregating for effect in-universe.
- Second of all JKR likes to exaggregate for effect the same way in general

  > 'Filch'll have me there all night,' said Ron heavily. 'No magic! There must be about a hundred cups in that room. I'm no good at Muggle cleaning.'
  >
  > 'I'll make it,' Lockhart butted in. 'I must have done it a hundred times, I could whip up a Mandrake Restorative Draught in my sleep –'
  >
  > 'I was so sure it was Malfoy' said Ron, for about the hundredth time.
- Some of the rules they broke (Bolded are the ones that are {almost} certain to be rules)

  - The "fifty rules" Hermione mentioned breaking to Polyjuice themselves.
  - Harry repeatedly lying to Dumbledore about not having anything important to tell him (like hearing the snake)
  - **Doing magic in the corridors**

    > Percy said, 'As a school Prefect –', but Harry had lost his temper. He pulled out his wand and shouted, 'Expelliarmus!' and just as Snape had disarmed Lockhart, so Malfoy found the diary shooting out of his hand into the air. Ron, grinning broadly, caught it.
    >   'Harry!' said Percy loudly. 'No magic in the corridors. I'll have to report this, you know!'
  - Fighting with a cupid dwarf in the corridor. Not sure if that's against school rules, but if I put on my McGonagall hat (yes I own one!), I think it would be.

  The rest will be subsequent to Hermione's petrificarion:

  - **Going to see Hagrid using Invisibility Cloak**
  - **Going to the Forbidden Forest**
  - **Talking to Acromantula** (classification XXXXX in Fantastic Beasts)
  - **Going to Moaning Mirtle's bathroom** (first, girls'! and second, going alone without an adult)
  - Lying to Prof. McGonagall that they were going to see Hermione in Hospital Wing when she caught them going to bathroom
  - Going alone into another corridor to teacher's staffroom
  - Listening in to teachers discussing another attack
  - NOT telling the teachers what they (or rather, Hermione) found.
  - Going alone to see Lockhart
  - **Pulling a wand on a teacher** (I won't count casting Expelliarmus as a sin)
  - **Forced Lockhart to go with them at wandpoint**
  - **Went to the girls' bathroom AGAIN**
  - Spoke in Parseltongue (not sure it's a sin, but I'll be as strict as McGonagle and ding them a point anyway)
  - **Pushed a professor down the entrance** (Ron "gave him a push", literally).
  - Spoke Parseltongue again to open the Chamber door
  - **Killed an endangered animal**
  - **Handled a highly cursed object** (2 of them - fang and diary)
  - **Lied to a Professor** (Lockhart) who he and they were

Comment: I love "Killed an endangered animal". This is McGonagall, remember, not Snape. "*She might be fairer than Snape,* but she was still extremely strict."

Comment: They did drive a wild car, no license, in the Forbidden Forest.

Comment: @DavidBanner - that's not against school rules. There's no driving licenses in Wizarding World and no muggles saw them

Comment: I chuckled at the endangered animal bit.

Comment: Is lying to teachers really set out as being against school rules? Speaking Parseltongue can't be, since Harry wasn't in any way punished when he did it at the Duelling Club. I also doubt handling the fang (which wasn't cursed, as far as I know, just venomous) would be against school rules, unless they had stolen it from Snape’s office, for example. And I don't recall anything anywhere about students needing to be accompanied by an adult to go to the bathroom, nor that going to the staff room (or to see a teacher) is against school rules. Do you have a source for these?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - You would make a VERY VERY poor Assistant Headmistress.

Comment: @DVK I should hope my gender would make me a very poor any kind of mistress!

Comment: Doesn't count to 100.

Comment: Good points, @DVK. Too bad the Ford Anglia didn't hit Voldemort in the Forest scene - movie 8. Best Deus ex Machina ever :)